# What causes HTMLUnit to throw " ReferenceError: "console" is not defined."?

Tags: maven, htmlunit, jasmine

I am trying to integrate jasmine into my MVN build to test my Javascript library.
It has now started throwing out the following error:

> ReferenceError: "console" is not defined.

Clearly it is my use of the console which is bugging it.
My coe actually tests for console's presence before using it, but MVN seems to dislike it non the less.

Any ideas whats casing it to cry out about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and unfortunately did not find a direct answer.  I did learn that using **alert() causes a log warning** which was quite useful.

For what it's worth, I've just got my **ExtJS 4, Jasmine, Maven learning project** working and it is available to the public at:
http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/extjs/

However, make sure you read the READ_ME.txt